# Decapitalize String Before Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have author and year nodes in a database with a relationship between them. I want to use `apoc.text.decapitalize` to turn `TotalPapers` into `totalPapers`.

When I run the following code, the `prop` returns as a string `"totalPapers"`, but the list is empty. However, when I replace `collect(r.prop)` with `collect(r.totalPapers)` everything seems to work fine.

```
MATCH (y:Year {year:2015})<-[r:IN]-(a:Author)
WITH r, apoc.text.decapitalize('TotalPapers') as prop
WITH r, prop, collect(r.prop) as stats
RETURN r, prop, stats
```

Any ideas on why this doesn't work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That query has a few errors and should not even execute. For instance, `m` is not defined. Please correct the query to match what you are actually using. Also, why are you calling `apoc.text.decapitalize()` on a string literal? Shouldn't you be using it on a property?

Comment: Fixed in the post. As for `apoc.text.decapitalize()`, I have a list of property names in Python as string literals, and I want to run this query for all of those property strings. The reason is I want to reuse those property names with the result of this to add to a new relationship property with a word before it while still being in camelCase, so having the string literal in Python allows me to do so. For example, the result I want from `TotalPapers` is to add a property called `venueTotalPapers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to understand what you are trying to do, but I will provide an answer anyway, in case it will help.

If you are trying to get, for all works authored in 2015, the `IN` relationship properties whose names match the decapitalization of "TotalPapers" (i.e., "totalPapers"), then the following should work. The `RETURN` clause omits `r` so that it is not used as a grouping key for the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) COLLECT, since that would always give you a list containing at most 1 value per relationship.

```
WITH apoc.text.decapitalize('TotalPapers') as prop
MATCH (y:Year {year: 2015})<-[r:IN]-(a:Author)
RETURN prop, COLLECT(r[prop]) as stats
```

And it would actually be best practice to pass 'TotalPapers' and 2015 as, say, `capitalizedProp` and `year` [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) to this query:

```
WITH apoc.text.decapitalize($capitalizedProp) as prop
MATCH (y:Year {year: $year})<-[r:IN]-(a:Author)
RETURN prop, COLLECT(r[prop]) as stats
```